# How to get value out of Observable Array nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, knockout.js

- I have searched here for an answer to this question with no luck.

I have an observable array which contains only one entry:

[image: Array]

I have it stored in **self.user()**

```
POSData.Users.getByEmail(sEmail)
        .then(data => {
        //console.log(data)
        self.user.push(data);
    })
```

Now I simply want to extract a few values and assign them to their own observables, BUT... I can't.

I have tried the following to get the firstName...

```
console.dir(self.user());

    //console.log(self.user()[0].data.firstName());
    //console.log(self.user().firstName());
    //console.log(self.user().data.firstName());
    //console.log(self.user()[0].data.firstName());
    //console.log(self.user().data[1].firstName());
```

Does anyone know how to drill down and get to the information I want?

Thanks for looking.

John

Comment: try doing a ko.toJS(self.user()) to see what structure you actually end up with after pushing the info.

Comment: it's empty apparently.... what in the world?!?! How can that be, when I console.log self.user()  it shows the data there.

Comment: can you put it in a fiddle (doesn't need knockout I just want to see the code in context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're storing the raw data you got back from your service into your array. You should access members of that data in that form. The `firstName` property is not an observable, it's just a string in the `data` property so you shouldn't be calling it as if it was an observable. The only observable in your example is apparently `self.user`.

Based on your screenshot your new data looks something like this:

```
{
  data: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  },
  message: 'User retrieved successfully',
  status: null
}
```

If you want to get the first name of this object in your `user` array, you'd access it like this:

```
self.user()[0].data.firstName
```